# Multi-line alignment : two pictures on the first line, third picture on the second line in a square fashion

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment, subfloats, texmaker

I have three picture to show, in three different aspect ratios, and I'd like to align them so that the two first have the same height on the first line and the third has the width of the two first, so that it appears as a square. The pictures ratios are landscape 4/3, portrait 16/9 for the two first, and landscape 16/9 for the third (so that you picture easily).

How can I achieve this ? For now, I tweaked the width and height by hand, but I would like a more automatic way or a way to make it work with `subfig`. Here's my code :

```
\begin{figure}[ht]

  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \begin{center}
      \includegraphics[height=7cm]{pic1}
      \includegraphics[height=7cm]{pic2}
    \end{center}
  \end{minipage}

  \quad

  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \begin{center}
      \includegraphics[width=15cm]{pic3}
    \end{center}
  \end{minipage}

\label{figpic}

\end{figure}
```

[image: not so neat multi line alignment example]

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Hi and welcome, if the height of the pictures is fitting as well, all you are looking for is an `\hfill` between the first two figures. At least i think so by a short look.

Comment: I am not sure, is the vertical placement an issue here as well? If you introduce subcaptions, everything will stretch vertically and the *square look* will be gone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The magic number is 91=64+27:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newlength{\preferredwidth}
\setlength{\preferredwidth}{12cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering

\begin{subfigure}{\dimexpr\preferredwidth*64/91}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-4x3}
\caption{Ratio 4:3 landscape}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{\dimexpr\preferredwidth*27/91}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-9x16}
\caption{Ratio 16:9 portrait}
\end{subfigure}

\medskip

\begin{subfigure}{\dimexpr\preferredwidth} 
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-16x9}
\caption{Ratio 16:9 landscape}
\end{subfigure}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The same with the images squashed together:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\newlength{\preferredwidth}
\setlength{\preferredwidth}{12cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering

\includegraphics[width=\dimexpr\preferredwidth*64/91]{example-image-4x3}%
\includegraphics[width=\dimexpr\preferredwidth*27/91]{example-image-9x16}\\
\includegraphics[width=\preferredwidth]{example-image-16x9}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Suppose the ratio of the top left and top right images are *r* and *s*, respectively. If the preferred width is *w*, then the width of the left image should be *rw*/(*r* + *s*) and the width of the right image should be *sw*/(*r* + *s*). In your case *r* = 4/3 and *s* = 9/16 which explains the magic number 91 = 4·16 + 3·9. The bottom image has no influence on the computation, so you won't get a square in any case.

Comment: Great and simple way to solve my problem, I now have the result I wanted. I have few more questions to completely understand the troubleshoot.

Where does this magic number come from ? How could I adapt this to other ratio (as for example 4x3 and 3x4 on the first line) ?
Plus, is it possible not to use `\newlength` and put the length directly in the `width` parameters ? And why 12 cm ?
Finally, how can I adjust the space between pics so that the horizontal and vertical gaps are equal ?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Hardbottle 12cm is just an attempt; use `\textwidth` or a fraction thereof. I'll add the computation of the magic number.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}% always use a complete document not a fragment

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]% include p

%  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth} a \textwidth minipage does nothing
\centering%\begin{center}

% mwe package images
      \sbox0{\includegraphics[height=4cm]{example-image-a}% no word space
      \includegraphics[height=4cm]{example-image-4x3}}

%  \quad ????

      \usebox{0}\\
      \includegraphics[width=\wd0]{example-image-a3-landscape}


\label{figpic}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```